# Reply-To Feature is not working as expected in GMAIL when two emails are set to reply to header

Tags: c#, vb.net, email, gmail, mailmessage

- In our application, we are using Common From Email address to send an email to all the users.
- To receive the reply back from the users, we use Reply to Header and we want users to send an email to 2 different users hence we use 2 email addresses in reply-to header.

When we reply to the email from Outlook, it works fine but in GMAIL, emails are going to Common From email address instead of Reply-To Email address.

When I use single email address in the REPLY-To header, functionality works fine. Issue is only when we use 2 email address in reply-to header.

```
mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(New MailAddress("1stReplyTo@domain.com"))
                    mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(New MailAddress("2ndReplyTo@domain.com"))
                    mailMessage.From = New MailAddress("commonEmailAddress@domain.com")
                    mailMessage.Body = "body"
                    mailMessage.Subject = "subject"
```

We were using this feature from last few years. But in a recent time we started facing this issue.

Comment: Have you contacted Google about this?

Comment: John: No Not Yet.

Comment: According to [RFC 5322/3.6 Field Definitions](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322) you are allowed 0 or 1 Reply-To headers. That it worked in Outlook is apparently an error.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: The OP's code shouldn't create multiple headers, though. The `Reply-To` header may contain either a single address or a comma-separated list of multiple addresses which to reply to. I assume the .NET Framework knows this and formats its list accordingly.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: This cannot be a bug in Outlook. I have tested in Yahoo and Hotmail and it is working fine. Moreover .net MailMessage class has given an option as "ReplyToList" which is a list and can be added as many as email. Seems like bug in GMAIL.

Comment: @John: Contacted Google and they asked me to post a question in StackOverFlow itself.

Comment: If you concede that it's probably a bug in Gmail, what can we possibly do to help?

Comment: @John. check this thread https://support.google.com/mail/thread/16125972?hl=en

Seeking help if some developer like me, if they had similar issue